# Problems with mathpazo and \mathcal with non-capital letters

Tags: mathpazo, mathcal

I am trying to use mathpazo font, but I have some issues getting the \mathcal working with small letters

this is my template

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{mathpazo}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\section{}
%\subsection{}

just some test  $ \infty \mathcal{l}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mathcal` works only for uppercase letters; `mathpazo` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: so, what is the way to use small letters and mathcal ? Since I probably mathpazo does not provide lowercase calligraphs, is there a way to load the calligraph's from another font gallery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The uppercase calligraphic letters are mapped to font `cmsy10`. The font does only contain calligraphic uppercase letters.

### Plain TeX version for font inspection

A font can be inspected using `testfont.tex` with plain formats (not LaTeX). LaTeX provides `nfssfont.tex`, derived from `testfont.tex`, see next section.

Example for an interactive session with `testfont`:

```
$ pdftex testfont
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
([...]/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/testfont.tex

Name of the font to test = cmsy10
Now type a test command (\help for help):)
*\help 

\init switches to another font;
\end or \bye finishes the run; 
\table prints the font layout in tabular format;
\text prints a sample text, assuming TeX text font conventions;
\sample combines \table and \text;
\mixture mixes a background character with a series of others;
\alternation interleaves a background character with a series;
\alphabet prints all lowercase letters within a given background;
\ALPHABET prints all uppercase letters within a given background;
\series prints a series of letters within a given background;
\lowers prints a comprehensive test of lowercase;
\uppers prints a comprehensive test of uppercase;
\digits prints a comprehensive test of numerals; 
\math prints a comprehensive test of TeX math italic;
\names prints a text that mixes upper and lower case;
\punct prints a punctuation test;
\bigtest combines many of the above routines;
\help repeats this message;
and you can use ordinary TeX commands (e.g., to \input a file).
*\table

*\bye
[1{[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
<[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.p
fb><[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7
.pfb><[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cm
sy10.pfb><[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmti10.pfb><[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on testfont.pdf (1 page, 72843 bytes).
Transcript written on testfont.log.
```

Or a driver file for non-interactive use can be created:

```
\let\noinit!
\input testfont
\def\fontname{cmsy10}
\startfont
\table
\bye
```

> [image: Result cmsy10]

### LaTeX version

`\mathcal` uses the mathematical symbol font (from `fontmath.ltx`):

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{symbols}
```

Package `mathpazo` contains the following font definition for symbols with encoding OMS:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
```

The latter four arguments are the same as for `\usefont` and are needed for `nfssfont.tex`. Example for an interactive session:

```
$ pdflatex nfssfont
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
([...]/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/nfssfont.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 77 languages loaded.
([...]/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls 
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
([...]/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No auxiliary output files.

**********************************************
* NFSS font test program version <v2.2b>
*
* Follow the instructions
**********************************************

Input external font name, e.g., cmr10
(or <enter> for NFSS classification of font):

\currfontname=


*** NFSS classification ***

Font encoding [T1]:

\encoding=OMS
([...]/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.def)
Font family [cmr]:

\family=zplm
Font series [m]:

\series=m
Font shape [n]:

\shape=n
Font size [10pt]:

\size=
([...]/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omszplm.fd)
Now type a test command (\help for help):)
*\table

*\bye
[1{[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
{[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}
<[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
<[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
<[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
<[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
<[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
<[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathpazo/fplmr.pfb>
<[...]/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/palatino/uplr8a.pfb>
Output written on nfssfont.pdf (1 page, 88770 bytes).
Transcript written on nfssfont.log.
```

The driver file for a non-interactive session can look like:

```
\let\noinit!
\input{nfssfont}
\def\encoding{OMS}
\usefont{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\edef\currfontname{\fontname\font}
\startfont
\table
\bye
```

> [image: Result OMS/zplm/m/n]

### Summary

For "calligraphic" lowercase letters you need a different font and cannot use `\mathcal`.

Comment: Actually the symbol font defined by `mathpazo` is `zplmr7y`

Comment: @egreg: That's a virtual font. The resolved font, embedded by pdfTeX, is `cmsy10.pfb`.

Comment: Not really: the fonts used are `cmsy10`, `fplmr` and `pplr8r`. The most important fact is that the OMS encoding doesn't have slots for lowercase calligraphic letters.

Comment: @egreg: Now I have also added the `nfssfont` variant with font `OMS/zplm/m/n`.